# How to convert osmium.osm.location cordinates to normal format coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, polar-coordinates, pyproj, pyosmium

I have extracted the coordinates data from nodes using pyosmium. Though I was successful in extracting the data but the coordinates which osmium is giving is not in normal format, I tried to convert the one of the coordinates using pyproj but the output is wrong. What is the best way to convert the pyosmium(osmium.osm.location) coordinates to normal coordinates?

```
The code tried:

    from pyproj import Proj, transform
    inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
    outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
    x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,-2916285,515160418)
    print(x2,y2)
Output I got:-
(-26.197433883484983, 90.0)
```